# Remove span tag when something removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tokenfield

I have an HTML structure and I want to remove an additional item.

```
<div class="tokenfield form-control">
    <input class="pro-credit-user" name="pro-credit-users[]" placeholder="Person or business name" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" type="text">
    <input style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" type="text">
    <div class="token invalid">
        <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 152px;">dfgdfgdf</span>
        <a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">×</a>
    </div>
    <input class="token-input ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Person or business name" id="1479230390171168-tokenfield" tabindex="0" style="min-width: 60px; width: 1237.4px;" type="text">
</div>

<a class="delete-pro-credit" href="#">Delete</a>
<span class="pro-credit-error" style="color:red;float:right">Sorry, this user cannot be found. We will not be able to link this persons name with an Enjoius account</span>
```

I have jQuery code also:

```
$("input.pro-credit-user").last().on('tokenfield:removetoken', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('span').remove(); // not working
})
```

When the user removes the token I also wanted to remove the span which has class 'pro-credit-error'. I have written jQuery but it's not working.

How can I remove that span which contains 'pro-credit-error' class?

Comment: In your code `.pro-credit-user` has no parent `span` element ?

Comment: What's `'tokenfield:removetoken'`?

Comment: @j08691 it's related to http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works for me:

```
$("input.pro-credit-user").last().on('tokenfield:removetoken', function (e) {
             $(e.relatedTarget).parent().prev().parent().find('span.pro-credit-error:eq(0)').remove();
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` work by traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. In this case the `span` you want to remove is not it's ancestor

Though not tested you can try this

```
 $("input.pro-credit-user").last().on('tokenfield:removetoken', function (e) {
              $(this).parent().sibling('span.pro-credit-error').remove();
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(this).next('span').remove();
```

Comment: Inputs don't have children

Comment: Do you want to remove span inside this div?
<div class="token invalid">
        <span class="token-label" style="max-width: 152px;">dfgdfgdf</span>
        <a href="#" class="close" tabindex="-1">×</a>
    </div>

Comment: I want to remove last span